# .sequelizerc: Sequelize-CLI con Typescript -> Error Path: Argumentos desconocidos

Tags: nodejs, typescript, sequelize.js

estoy utilizando un cliente de sequelize de terminal para Typescript:
https://github.com/douglas-treadwell/sequelize-cli-typescript

En mi archivo de configuración (que funcionaba perfecto con sequelize-cli para javascript) tengo rutas diferentes para mis carpetas de modelos, migraciones y seeders.

El problema es que al pasarme a sequelize-cli para typescript esas configuraciones no me funcionaban.

Investigando en el repositorio de github encontré esta mención importante:

> It's usually the case that the compiled JavaScript code will be put in a different directory than the source TypeScript code, so whereas sequelize-cli had one migrations-path setting, sequelize-cli-typescript has two: migrations-source-path and migrations-compiled-path, which default to /migrations and /migrations/compiled respectively.

Así que las actualicé como en las indicaciones.

Los cuales tengo (.sequelizerc):

```
    'models-path': path.resolve( 'src/app', 'models' ),
    'seeders-path': path.resolve( 'src/database', 'seeders' ),
    'migrations-source-path': path.resolve( 'src/database', 'migrations' ),
    'migrations-compiled-path': path.resolve( 'dist/src/database', 'migrations' ),


    'config': {}
```

Pero al arrancar el comando sequelize en terminal me aparecen los siguientes errores:

```
Argumentos desconocidos: models-path, seeders-path, migrations-source-path, migrations-compiled-path, config
```

Cómo lo soluciono? Hay alguna otra manera de hacer funcionar sequelize-cli con typescript?

Estoy trabajando todo mi proyecto en tsc.

Comment: Si comentas `migrations-source-path` y `migrations-compiled-path` (ya que apuntan por defecto a `migrations/` y `migrations/compiled` respectivamente), ¿ejecuta sin errores?

Comment: Tampoco funciona con migrations-path, de hecho tampoco reconoce models-path ni seeders-path.

Otra forma que me serviría (que desconozco aún) sería usar sequelize-cli tradicional pero de alguna forma integrarlo con typescript. No conozco el método